# looping through database records using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to display all the users of my admin page, but when I load the admin view it only displays the first record.

users_model

```
public function display_all_users()
{


        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $this->db->select('first_name,last_name,email,age,address');
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

users controller

```
public function admin_view() {
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    if($this->session->userdata('is_loged_in')) {

     $display['view_users'] = $this->User_model->display_all_users();

      $this->load->view('admin/view_users',$display);  

    }  else {
        redirect('Users/restricted');
    } 
}
```

view

```
  <?php foreach ($display as $row): ?>

     <p>

       <?php echo $row['first_name'];?>
       <?php echo $row['last_name'];?>
       <?php echo $row['email'];?>
       <?php echo $row['age'];?>
       <?php echo $row['address'];?>
    </p>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the wrong variable, remember arrays are split into separate variables.

Your `foreach` signature should instead be:

```
foreach ($view_users as $row):
```